# Getting the NextAuth session with EmailProvider inside getServerSideProps throws fs "module not found"

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemailer, next-auth

I'm trying to get the NextAuth session from a server-side call in `getServerSideProps`, and I'm using an `EmailProvider` with NextAuth. I'm following an example from [NextAuth's documentation](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/main/pages/server.tsx) to get the session from `getServerSideProps`.

In the `[...nextauth].ts]` configuration file, I use the `EmailProvider`.

```
// pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({ ... }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

In a frontend component, I attempt to get the session like this:

```
// components/MyComponent.tsx

import { authOptions } from '@auth/[...nextauth]';

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  const serverSession = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
  
  return {
    props: { serverSession },
  };
};
```

I even added webpack configs in `next.config.js` to ignore server-only code when on the client:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer, webpack }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^\/pages\/api\/auth\/$/ })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I add `import { authOptions } from '@auth/[...nextauth]';` to my frontend component file, it throws a compilation error:

```
// compilation error
error - ./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/dkim/index.js:10:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./node_modules/next-auth/providers/email.js
./pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
./components/MyComponent.tsx
./pages/index.tsx
```

I guess this is expected behavior when I import `[...nextauth]` in `MyComponent`, it imports `EmailProvider`, which imports `nodemailer`, and `nodemailer` imports `fs`. Since `MyComponent` runs on the client, it throws an error, because `fs` module is not available on the client.

So I've tried a few things:

- add `"fs": false` to my `package.json` ([source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011612/931746)) This works as a bandaid solution, but then more modules need to get added to `package.json`, and I go down a rabbit hole that eventually prevents `prisma` from being used.
- Import `authOptions` inside `getServerSideProps` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611405/how-to-best-import-server-only-code-in-next-js)). This did not affect the error.

Any other ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah so *components* can't do server-side rendering (SSR), only *pages* can. Here's [more documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering).

So to fix this, I moved `getServerSideProps` to a page (e.g. `pages/index.tsx` or any other page in the root of `pages/`). The code looks the same, which is copied below, but the file that the code lives in is different.

```
// components/MyComponent.tsx <-- this is wrong
// ^^ IT SHOULD NOT BE A COMPONENT

// pages/index.tsx <-- or whatever page you're using
// ^^ IT SHOULD BE A PAGE INSTEAD OF A COMPONENT

import { authOptions } from '@auth/[...nextauth]';

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  const serverSession = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
  
  return {
    props: { serverSession },
  };
};
```